# Best way to implement UIPopoverView on iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6, uipopovercontroller

It's available on iPad, but unfortunately not on iPhone. I want to use a service such as this to display some options to the user without summoning a new viewcontroller, and I'm curious what the best library/way to do this is.

I found this one: https://github.com/runway20/PopoverView

Which seems fantastic, but it is a little outdated, and hasn't been updated for iOS 6 (gives a lot of warnings in regards to deprecated methods being used).

Comment: [WEPopover](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover) is a decent attempt at this. It's also pretty out of date, but I'm using it in an iOS 6 project with a few small modifications, and it works well.

Comment: FFPopover seems to be recently updated and robust. I'm going to look into that, thanks. And thanks CodaFi, that was lazy negligence on my part, sorry.